# Symfony3 - tree rendering

Tags: symfony, twig

I start with symfony and I try to create a blog with comments. A comment may be a response to another comment: in this case, it is slightly shifted to the right to show the comment tree. There can be no more than 3 sub-levels of comments. Here is my Comment Entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Comment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * Number of levels comments
     */
    const NUM_LEVELS = 3;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment", inversedBy="childs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $childs;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="signaled", type="boolean")
     */
    private $signaled = false;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer")
     */
    private $level = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param string $author
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Article $article
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setArticle(\AppBundle\Entity\Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Article
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->childs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->date = new \Datetime();
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Comment $parent
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setParent(\AppBundle\Entity\Comment $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Comment
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Comment $child
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function addChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Comment $child)
    {
        $this->childs[] = $child;
        $child->setParent($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Comment $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Comment $child)
    {
        $this->childs->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get childs
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChilds()
    {
        return $this->childs;
    }

    /**
     * Set signaled
     *
     * @param boolean $signaled
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setSignaled($signaled)
    {
        $this->signaled = $signaled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get signaled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getSignaled()
    {
        return $this->signaled;
    }

    /**
     * Set level
     *
     * @param integer $level
     *
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setLevel($level)
    {
        if ($level >= $this::NUM_LEVELS) {
            $this->level = $this::NUM_LEVELS;
        } elseif ($level < 0) {
            $this->level = 0;
        } else {
            $this->level = $level;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get level
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLevel()
    {
        return $this->level;
    }
}
```

Today, I manage to post comments and responses to comments with these actions in the controller:

```
/**
 * Display form to add a NEW comment
 *
 * @Route("/articles/{slug}/comments/add", name="addComment")
 *
 */
public function addCommentAction(Article $article, Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setArticle($article);
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();
        $request->getSession()->getFlashbag()->add('success', 'Le commentaire a bien été enregistré');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('view_article', array('slug' => $article->getSlug()));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'Article/addComment.html.twig',
        [
            'article' => $article,

            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );

}

/**
 * Display form to add a NEW comment
 *
 * @Route("/articles/{slug}/comments/add", name="addComment")
 *
 */
public function addCommentAction(Article $article, Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setArticle($article);
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();
        $request->getSession()->getFlashbag()->add('success', 'Le commentaire a bien été enregistré');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('view_article', array('slug' => $article->getSlug()));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'Article/addComment.html.twig',
        [
            'article' => $article,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
}
```

What would be the best rendering solution in my Twig template to display the tree view?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: I would suggest you to use Doctrine extension - [Gedmo Tree](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md). It uses different structure in database (preorder tree), but it allows to grab all comments in single query with all needed information. After, you will be able to render your tree using only `level` information. At this moment your code needs recursion, which can be avoided with proposed extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try to use this doctrine extension.